# Django Models: Should a relatives model refer to itself through ForeignKey or ManyToMany?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, model

I'm creating a django app where the a model class, Character has relatives, which are actually other Character models. However, I'm not sure how I should set this up. Right now I'm thinking about using something like this:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    sex = models.CharField()
    link = models.URLField()
    appearance = models.ManyToManyField(Episode, related_name="characters")
    relatives = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name="characters")
```

However, I'm  not sure if this is quite right...maybe I should use ManyToManyField? An example of a character could be Tim. Tim has relatives, Bobby, David, and Whiskers. Bobby has relatives David and Tim. David has relatives Bobby and Tim. Whiskers has relative Tim. Also, if a class's field points to the same class, will this be an issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if a class's field points to the same class, will this be an issue?
```

this is not an issue and most sql databases support this. Read more on self-joins to understand this.

```
maybe I should use ManyToManyField?
```

yes, manytomany is the way to go forward as one person can have many relatives & he himself can be the relative of many others.